# How can I place html text on top of a canvas flot chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, flot

Here's my simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19f7q0x4/).  I'm looking to place HTML text on top of the flot chart. Or put flot chart in the background (depending on how you think about it).

[image: text on top of flot]

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Place me on top please. How?!</h1>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { position:relative; }
h1 { z-index:100; color:blue; font-size:5em; margin:0; line-height:0.9em; }
#placeholder {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

JS (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19f7q0x4/) for the rest) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    chart = $.plot($("#placeholder"),data,options);
});
```

Comment: For some reason setting the #placeholder with a z-index of -1 works for me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `position: absolute;` to the h1 in your css...

> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

[source of this quoted text](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
#wrapper { position:relative; }
h1 { z-index:100; color:blue; position: absolute; font-size:5em; margin:0; line-height:0.9em; }
#placeholder {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[:::: JSFIDDLE ::::](http://jsfiddle.net/19f7q0x4/3/)

Comment: Or `position: relative` to take advantage of the `z-index` without positioning.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the positioning of the h1 absolute

```
h1 { z-index:100; color:blue; font-size:5em; margin:0; line-height:0.9em; position:absolute;}
```

Worked for me